# How many extra wallets can I buy? / What are the maximum number of Rupees I can carry?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In addition to having different sized Wallets, Beedle's shop also stocks extra wallets, which allow you to carry an extra 300 coins each.

After buying one, you can leave the shop and come back to buy another one.

How many Extra Wallets can you buy?

On a related note, what is the maximum number of Rupees you can carry at a time with the largest wallet and as many Extra Wallets you can carry?

Comment: I was able to buy 3 extra wallets, and have already received an upgrade to my base wallet. After you buy 3 extra wallet beedle stops carrying them, but he may restock later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only buy **3** extra wallets from **Beedle**, each with a capacity of **300 rupees** giving you an additional capacity of **900 rupees**.

The largest wallet that I was able to obtain was the **Giant Wallet** which you get from one of the special quests.

> You get it from **Batreaux** after giving him **50 Gratitude Crystals**.

That gives you a base capacity of **5000 rupees** for a grand total of **5900 rupees** when you include the extra wallets.

There is an even larger wallet, the **Tycoon Wallet** which gives you a base capacity of **9000 rupees** bringing you to a grand total of **9900 rupees** carryable max.

> You get it from **Batreaux** after giving him **80 Gratitude Crystals**.

Comment: The most expensive item in the game AFAIK would be the `Heart Piece` sold by `Beedle`.  That would cost you a whopping `1600` rupees.  So you'll probably want to be able to hold at least that much rupees.  So you'll need (at a minimum) the `Big Wallet` (`1000` rupee capacity) with 3 extra wallets for a total capacity of `1900` rupees.

Comment: Completing Beedle's sidequest allows you to purchase one item at half price. If you saved the Heart Piece for that purchase, then I believe the second most expensive item is the final Adventure Pouch upgrade at 1200 Rupees. Thus, it is just barely possible to buy everything buyable in the game without ever upgrading your base wallet.

Comment: Correction: I believe you still need to have 1600 rupees to get the Heart Piece at half price - this is how it works in most games. I might be wrong, though. Another correction: Four Swords (GBA or the 3DS Anniversary Edition) has the highest Rupee total: 999,999. Although I think the original (GBA) version only went up to 99,999 since it didn't keep tabs of your grand total, so it wouldn't be possible to get over a 100k in the Hero key version of Vaati's Palace.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Zelda Wiki](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Wallet), the maximum number of Rupees you can carry is 9,000.

Comment: Holy geez, that's a lot higher than any other game in the series.  I guess it's good that I won't be filling my wallet up every 5 minutes, now!

Comment: @Shinrai: No it isn't, you can carry 9,999 in the two DS installments.  It actually confused me when I started Phantom Hourglass the first time and saw my starting Rupees were 0000.

Comment: Ahh, I've not played either of those.  I didn't even think they had any stores - I was under the impression they didn't have traditional towns or overworld.

Comment: @Shinrai that would be a mistaken impression. There is stuff to buy at several towns. You can even visit Beedle. You are correct in that they don't have a traditional overworld (but neither did wind waker, think of the DS games as similar to WW in that regard)

Comment: This answer is incorrect for Skyward Sword; as the selected answer (as well as the wiki page you linked to) shows, you can have a maximum of **9,900** Rupees.